# Python pandas - averaging 10 min measurements to 15min mean and 60min mean depending on the length of the data gap

Tags: python, pandas, mean, na

i'm quite new in programming with pyhton and  I hope anyone of you is in mood to help me.

Well, i have many differnt climate stations with solar radiation measurements in a 1 minute and also in 10 minutes time resolution. The measurements contains also Na values.
Now I'd like to calculate the averages with a 15min and 60min time resolution, but the possiblity should be given to take the length of the data gaps into account. If the data gaps in the underlaying time span are bigger than a relative number (for example 20% ) of available values in this time span than do nothing otherwise build the average. 
For example:
- the hourly average for 12 o'clock should be NA cause there are 50% NAs in the underlying time span

```
09.08.2011 11:10    553
09.08.2011 11:20    567   
09.08.2011 11:30    NA
09.08.2011 11:40    NA
09.08.2011 11:50    NA
09.08.2011 12:00    NA
```

- the average for 1 o'clock shoul be NA cause 100% NAs (see data example below)
- the average for 2 o'clock should be 210.6 cause there are only 16.7% NA in the underlying hour

my data look like this:

```
09.08.2011 10:00    189       
09.08.2011 10:10    337       
09.08.2011 10:20    567       
09.08.2011 10:30    432       
09.08.2011 10:40    634       
09.08.2011 10:50    965       
09.08.2011 11:00    897       
09.08.2011 11:10    553       
09.08.2011 11:20    567       
09.08.2011 11:30    NA       
09.08.2011 11:40    NA       
09.08.2011 11:50    NA   
09.08.2011 12:00    NA   
09.08.2011 12:20    NA   
09.08.2011 12:30    NA
09.08.2011 12:40    NA
09.08.2011 12:50    NA
09.08.2011 13:00    NA
09.08.2011 13:10    NA
09.08.2011 13:20    445
09.08.2011 13:30    115
09.08.2011 13:40    34
09.08.2011 13:50    128
09.08.2011 14:00    331


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_csv_data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(station_path, skiprows=5,  parse_dates= True, index_col=0, na_values=[-999], names= names_header , sep=' ', header=None , squeeze=True)

ts15 = df_csv_data.resample('15Min', how='mean')
ts60 = df_csv_data.resample('60Min', how='mean')
```

I'd like to solve this problem with a relative number of data gaps cause of the different desired time resolution.

Has anyone an idea to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

steff

`

Comment: Please give some code to reproduce a similar DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Setup problem
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_samples = 100
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 500, num_samples), index=pd.date_range('03/06/2015', periods=num_samples, freq='10min'))
mask = np.random.rand(num_samples) < .7
s[mask] = np.nan

# Loop through index
# Note the perc_nan variable can be changed depending on what percentage of the interval must be nan for the mean value to also be nan
perc_nan = 0.5
data, indices = [], []
for dt in s.index:
    if dt.minute == 0:
        d = s[('00:00:00' <= dt - s.index) & (dt - s.index < '01:00:00')]
        data.append(d.mean() if d.isnull().sum() <= len(d)*perc_nan else np.nan)
        indices.append(dt)

# Solution
pd.Series(data, index=indices)
```

Comment: thanks for your help!u

what does this line mean?
mask = np.random.rand(num_samples) < .7

Comment: That just a boolean mask that is later used to set some items to np.nan. Ex. array([ True, False,  True,  False,  True], dtype=bool). It's sole use is to set some elements to np.nan (at random).

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: it's close to what i need.
the problem now is that all measurements with 0 are NAs.
how can I declare 0 as true values in a serie

Comment: Not sure I understand but maybe this will help .... `s.fillna(0)` - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html

Comment: in the measurements are NAs which are the missing values and there are also 0 which are true values. in mty serie the NAs and the 0 are NA values. how can i handle the true value. sorry for the bad formatting 
data look like this:
01.01.2011 00:00 NA

01.01.2011 00:10  0

01.01.2011 00:20  0

01.01.2011 00:30  0

01.01.2011 00:40  0

.....
.....
01.01.2011 09:00 40

01.01.2011 09:10 47

01.01.2011 09:20 47

01.01.2011 09:30 47

01.01.2011 09:40 47

01.01.2011 09:50 47

01.01.2011 10:00 54

01.01.2011 10:10 67

01.01.2011 10:20 74

01.01.2011 10:30 74

01.01.2011 10:40 67

01.01.2011 10:50 61

Comment: yes - the posted data above are a part of the underlying measurements from one climate station. and in the pd.serie the 0 values are NaNs.

Comment: That must be something to do with how you are reading the data in.